# How to Convert gdaldem.cpp file into gdaldem.java?

Tags: java-native-interface, swig, gdal, java-binding

I want to use gdaldem in java program so I want to convert gdaldem.cpp into the gdaldem.java. Please tell me a solution regarding this.
If any other solution is there to use gdaldem in java please tell me that also.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off using an existing java interface to GDAL than trying to roll your own translation of a single program. Especially if are having questions about how to convert a c++ program to java.

[GDALOGRinJava](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInJava)